# merge and show each content together

Tags: shell, awk

i have two lists with same length and same contents:

```
   file1            file2 
    apple            apple 
    cat              cat
    dog              dog
    frog             frog
```

i want to write a shell script which gives me the output like below:

```
 output.txt  
    apple apple
    apple cat
    apple dog
    apple frog
    cat apple
    cat cat
    cat dog
    cat frog
    dog apple
    ...  ...
```

can anybody help me on this??

Comment: Are these 2 lists in 2 different files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be many questions to your question eg--> do you need same order of strings as per their line number? only based on your shown sample Input_file(s) could you please try following and let me know if this helps.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$0;v=FNR;next} {for(i=1;i<=v;i++){print $0,a[i]}}'  Input_file1  Input_file2
```

Output will be as follows.

```
apple apple
apple cat
apple dog
apple frog
cat apple
cat cat
cat dog
cat frog
dog apple
dog cat
dog dog
dog frog
frog apple
frog cat
frog dog
frog frog
```

Adding explanation too here on same.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{        ##Checking here condition if FNR==NR, which will be only TRUE when first Input_file is getting read. FNR and NR both represents number of lines in a Input_file, only difference between them is FNR value will be RESET whenever it starts reading a next Input_file, on other hand NR value will be keep increasing till it reads all the Input_files.
 a[FNR]=$0;      ##Creating an array named a whose index current line number and value is current line too.
 v=FNR;         ##Creating a variable named V here whose value is value of FNR value.
 next           ##next is awk out of the box keyword which will skip all further statements.
}
{               ##This block statements will be executed when 2nd Input_file is being read.
for(i=1;i<=v;i++){   ##Starting a for loop, which will traverse through an array
 print $0,a[i]       ##Printing the value of current line along with value of array a whose index is value of variable named i.
}}
' Input_file1 Input_file2    ##Mentioning the Input_files here.
```

Answer (score 1):

you want a cross product, here is an easy way to do it

```
join -j9 file1 file2
```

Comment: This is elegant solution so far here.. ++